# Program is finding num of sentences words and letters and calculating reading level. Bug appears when it should output "grade 8" but it output grade 9

Tags: c, cs50, readability

when you input -

> Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, "and what is the use of a book," thought Alice "without pictures or conversation?"

it should output grade 8 but it outputs grade 9

```
 #include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    float l = 0;
    float w = 1;
    float s = 0;

// get text from user
string text= get_string("Your text:");

//string longiness
     int length = strlen(text);


    for (int k = 0; k < length; k++)
{
// num of all letters
        if isalpha(text[k])
        {
             l++;
        }

// num of words
            if isalpha(text[k])
            {
       if (isspace(text[k-1]) || text[k-1] == '!' || text[k-1] == '.' || text[k-1] == '?')
    {
       w++;
    }
            }   

// num of sentences
    if (text[k] == '!' || text[k] == '.' || text[k] == '?')
    {
       s++;
    }
    
}


// calculating avarge of letters per 100 words
float L = l / w * 100;
// calculating average number of sentences per 100 words
float S = s / w * 100;

// Coleman-Liau index calculating
int index = round((0.0588 * L) - (0.296 * S) - 15.8);

// output: what grade is text for
if (index < 1)
printf("Before Grade 1\n");

  else if (index <= 16 && index > 1)
        printf("Grade %i\n", index);
        
    else
printf("Grade 16+\n");

}
```

Comment: In the `// num of words` test condition you need to begin with `k == 0 ||` otherwise you'll be indexing out of range with `text[k-1]`

Comment: WOW!!! I never realized the preprocessor makes `if isalpha(something)` a valid construction... Mertin27: you **need** the parenthesis around the condition of `if`s ... `if (isalpha(something))`. **Pro Tip: don't write code without the parenthesis even if it *works***.

Comment: Output the cumulative counts for each character that you input. Then you'll know where it misfires.

Comment: `if (isspace(text[k-1]) || ...` is a problem when `k == 0`.

Comment: Mertin27, Aside: why `float` variables yet using `double`  math: `round((0.0588 * L) - (0.296 * S) - 15.8)`.  Recommend `double` variables.

Comment: Mertin27, If input was `"Hello World\n"`, is that 1 or 0 sentences?

Comment: Mertin27 `w` count is wrong.  [@pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67861004/2410359) provides a partial fix.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the indentation of your code

> ```
> // num of words
> if (isalpha(text[k]))             // I added missing parenthesis
> {
>     if (isspace(text[k-1]) || text[k-1] == '!' || text[k-1] == '.' || text[k-1] == '?')
>     {
>         w++;
>     }
> }
> ```

Your code does not count the `without` word in `thought Alice "without pictures` because it starts with a quote.

And, as stated in comments, you need to prevent access to `text[-1]` which causes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: `isspace(text[k-1])` also needs fix to avoid `text[0-1]`.

Comment: Thanks chux, added that note into my answer.

Comment: Good spot that `"without` is not counted as a word.  Yet OP's word and sentence count algorithm is overall problematic..

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica https://cs50.harvard.edu/college/2021/spring/psets/2/readability/ here is said that you should count sentences by punctuation as . ? !

Comment: @Mertin27  [In practice, sentence boundary detection needs to be a little more intelligent](https://cs50.harvard.edu/college/2021/spring/psets/2/readability/])  `". ? !"` is  step 1 of many.